# Google IO Sched App - Tablet Layout & Fragments

Tags: android, layout, tablet, android-fragments, googleio

Am I just being dumb or what.

So checking out the IO Sched source I wanted to see how they got a different layout on the tablet home activity than the phone home activity.

Am I looking at the latest source version?
https://github.com/underhilllabs/iosched

So here is activity_home.xml:

https://github.com/underhilllabs/iosched/blob/master/res/layout/activity_home.xml

And it basically is just describing the action bar and the dashboard layout.

However on the tablet the home activity also shows a realtime stream fragment.

On the IO video he is describing these screens with fragments here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGIU2JX1U5Y&feature=player_embedded#t=2561s

I've also checked the HomeActivity class and this doesn't seem to do it:

https://github.com/underhilllabs/iosched/blob/master/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/HomeActivity.java

so I cannot see how or were the layout for the Tablet is working and where the fragments have been declared. Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a fork of the original which is at http://code.google.com/p/iosched . In the original code, there are some additional layouts for different screen sizes and OS versions.  I think that the "Honeycomb Xlarge Landscape" [layout directory](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#hg/android/res/layout-xlarge-land-v11) has what you're looking for.

Comment: Perfect, I was thinking it was a bit strange. Cheers Mark. You can't browse the code online at code.google that's why I like github :-) *EDIT* Ah you can would help if I clicked the 'browse' button :-D